# How to show and hide modal dialog using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dialog and I want to show/hide it using pure javascript. I used modal.classList.add('hide'); it hides it but then the whole screen freezes I cannot click on anything. The hide and show animation are the most important for the dialog I am building that is why I took this approach.There is my modal dialog

```
 <div class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" >
          <div class="modal-header">
            <a class="close button">

              <paper-button raied  type="button" class="close" id="close" aria-hidden="true" on-click="close">Close</paper-button>
            </a>
            <h2 class="modal-title">Title</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body next">
            <img class='modal-img' />
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <paper-button raied id="previous" type="button" class="pull-left prev" on-click="prev">Previous</paper-button>
            <paper-button raied id="next" type="button" class="next" on-click="next">Next</paper-button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the function for closing the dialog and the CSS:

```
close: function() {
        var modal = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(".modal");
        //modal.style.display = "none";
        modal.classList.add('hide');

      }
```

and here it is my stylesheet:

```
<style>
@keyframes show {
    0% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    1% {
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@keyframes hide {
    0% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        display: block;
    }
    100% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
.element, .element-css {
    animation: show 500ms linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.hide{
    animation: hide 500ms linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
</style>
```

Comment: can you create a **demo fiddle** for this? I assume this isn't `twitter-bootstrap` `modal` you are talking about

Comment: No it is not twitter bootstrap. I used polymer and neon-animation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-dialog',
    behaviors: [
    Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
    ],
    properties: {
        opened: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    animationConfig: {
        value: function() {
        return {
          'entry': {
            // provided by neon-animation/animations/scale-up-animation.html
            name: 'scale-up-animation',
            node: this
          },
          'exit': {
            // provided by neon-animation-animations/fade-out-animation.html
            name: 'fade-out-animation',
            node: this
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  listeners: {
    'neon-animation-finish': '_onNeonAnimationFinish'
  },
  show: function() {
    this.opened = true;
    this.style.display = 'inline-block';
    // run scale-up-animation
    this.playAnimation('entry');
  },
  hide: function() {
    this.opened = false;
    // run fade-out-animation
    this.playAnimation('exit');
  },
  _onNeonAnimationFinish: function() {
    if (!this.opened) {
      this.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

Html

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" >
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close button">

          <paper-button raied  type="button" class="close" id="close" aria-hidden="true" on-click="close">Close</paper-button>
        </a>
        <h2 class="modal-title">Title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body next">
        <img class='modal-img' />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <paper-button raied id="previous" type="button" class="pull-left prev" on-click="prev">Previous</paper-button>
        <paper-button raied id="next" type="button" class="next" on-click="next">Next</paper-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also have a look at the jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/samshameem/gcg9ryoz/)

Comment: This is jquery, I need it in javascript

Comment: @BesaNeziri where is the jQuery part in this?

Comment: It was another answer that I wrote that comment to. This is edited

Comment: @Shameem I will check it out. Thank you

Comment: @Besa You are Welcome. Please feel free to ask any query. If you are satisfied with answer please mark it as your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add `visibility: hidden` in your hide keyframe at 100% and `visibility: visible` in 0% and so the show keyframe.

Hope that helps

Comment: check this out https://jsfiddle.net/pbgfdvwb/. I'm pretty sure it will work though if there something wrong on your css that prevents your modal from disappearing totally like default values in your `.modal` css rule `display: block`, `visibility: visible` are the first one's I could see that could interfere after animation has ended. You should remove it since animation will put it anyways and since you use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`